# Why is $\ \frac{1}{2}(p^{rmn-r})(p^r - 3)\ $ odd?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $p>2$ be prime and $m,n,r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Why is $$\frac{1}{2}(p^{rmn-r})(p^r - 3)$$ an odd number when $p \equiv_4 1$ or when $r$ is even?

I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: If $\ p\ $ is of the form $\ 4k+1\ $ , the first factor after $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ is obviously odd and the third has the form $\ 4k+2\ $. Since $\ p\ $ is odd, the same holds if $\ r\ $ is even since $\ p^r\ $ is then a square of an odd number , hence of the form $\ 4k+1\ $.

Comment: Why is the third factor of the form 4k+2?